# Place element center to top left with css in order to reference "transform" to the element's center

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I want to place an element's center, at the same place where was clicked:
[image: while click]
[image]

For this, I want to use transform, but for the initial css property I can't use:

```css
#element{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
   transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Because the initial reference position is the same and when using [transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp), it won't work when translating, take these examples:

```js
let action1=document.querySelector("#actions1");
let action2=document.querySelector("#actions2");
let action3=document.querySelector("#actions3");
let action4=document.querySelector("#actions4");
let boton1=document.querySelector("#me1");
let boton2=document.querySelector("#me2");
let boton3=document.querySelector("#me3");
let boton4=document.querySelector("#me4");
boton1.addEventListener("click",move1);
boton2.addEventListener("click",move2);
boton3.addEventListener("click",move3);
boton4.addEventListener("click",move4);
function move1(e){
  let startX=e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
  let startY=e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
  action1.style.display="grid";
  action2.style.display="none";
  action3.style.display="none";
  action4.style.display="none";
  action1.style.transform="translate("+startX+"px,"+startY+"px)";
}
function move2(e){
  let startX=e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
  let startY=e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
  action2.style.display="grid";
  action1.style.display="none";
  action3.style.display="none";
  action4.style.display="none";
  action2.style.transform="translate("+startX+"px,"+startY+"px)";
}
function move3(e){
  let startX=e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
  let startY=e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
  action3.style.display="grid";
  action1.style.display="none";
  action2.style.display="none";
  action4.style.display="none";
  action3.style.transform="translate("+startX+"px,"+startY+"px)";
}
function move4(e){
  let startX=e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
  let startY=e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
  action4.style.display="grid";
  action1.style.display="none";
  action2.style.display="none";
  action3.style.display="none";
  let size=action4.getBoundingClientRect();
  action4.style.top=startY-(size.height/2)+"px";
  action4.style.left=startX-(size.width/2)+"px";
}
```

```css
#actions1,#actions2,#actions3,#actions4{
  display:none;grid-template-columns:auto;grid-gap:5px;
    padding:10px;
}
#actions1{
    position:fixed;top:0;left:0;
}
#actions2{
    position:fixed;top:0;left:0;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#actions3{
    position:fixed;top:-40px;left:-45px;
}
#actions4{
    position:fixed;top:0;left:0;
}
#botons{
  position:fixed;
  top: 50px;left:0;right:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div id="botons">
 <button id="me1">normal</button>
 <button id="me2">not posible to reference with transform</button>
 <button id="me3">desirable</button>
 <button id="me4">old school</button>
</div>
 <div id="actions1">
        <button>open1</button>
        <button>new1</button>
        <button>delete1</button>
 </div>
 <div id="actions2">
        <button>open2</button>
        <button>new2</button>
        <button>delete2</button>
 </div>
 <div id="actions3">
        <button>open3</button>
        <button>new3</button>
        <button>delete3</button>
 </div>
 <div id="actions4">
        <button>open4</button>
        <button>new4</button>
        <button>delete4</button>
 </div>
```

As you can see, the first example and the second behave the same way because the initial reference position of the element does not change, both have:

```css
#element{
    position:fixed;top:0;left:0;
}
```

The third example shows the desirable result, but this method makes me know the width and the height all the time, it won't work if I add children to this element, the last example shows how the old school would do it, that would be taking the size and then divide by 2, the problem with this is that it's a hack, and because transform has [better](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) performance over changing position directly.

Comment: So where ever you click the screen, you want the element/button to be positioned center of the click?

Comment: exactly, but using transform, not "top,left,right"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click anywhere in the demo button it will reveal a `.dropdown-menu` at the center point of your cursor click, within the button.

Not too hacky either because its `position: absolute` inside the `.btn-group` using `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to centre it nicely based on top left.

You can add as many buttons to the `.dropdown-menu` and it will always be centred on your click.

It's probably best to render the buttons inside the `.dropdown-menu` on page load, but if you have dynamic buttons to add via javascript then append the buttons how ever you need.

You need to trigger a `.hide()` a `.dropdown-menu` method when clicking off the menu which should be easy enough.

See http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/sdn5eboa/ too if you wanna play.

Run code below to see example...

```js
// demo button click event
$('.btn-demo').on('click', function(e) {
 
  // get the next element matching .dropdown-menu
  var $dropdown_menu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
 
  // your custom button or add these however method you are doing
  var btn_1 = '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Button 1</button>';
  var btn_2 = '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Button 2</button>';
  var btn_3 = '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Button 3</button>';
  
  // add the desired buttons to the .dropdown-menu on click
  $dropdown_menu.html(btn_1 + btn_2 + btn_3);
  
  // add this css to .dropdown-menu menu on click
  $dropdown_menu.css({
  
    //  top postion: cursor click postion minus .btn-demo top-offset position
    top: (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top),
   
    // left postion: cursor click postion minus .btn-demo left-offset position
    left: (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left),
    
    // display block to reveal the .dropdown-menu or use .show() function
    // display: 'block'
    
  }).show();

});
```

```css
@import 'http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';

HTML,
BODY {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  cursor: crosshair;
  width: 100%;
}

BUTTON {
  cursor: crosshair !important;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- demo containers to center .btn-group please ignore this -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      
      <!-- question related code only -->
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-demo">
          Long demo button title for testing
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu"></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Translate only version**

See below `transform: translate()` only version to position the dropdown menu centre inside button on the mouse cursor.

Here is a jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/2qLvp5a3/

```js
// demo button click event
$('.btn-demo').on('click', function(e) {

  // get the next element matching .dropdown-menu
  var $dropdown_menu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');

  // your custom button or add these however method you are doing
  var btn_1 = '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Button 1</button>';
  var btn_2 = '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Button 2</button>';
  var btn_3 = '<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Button 3</button>';

  // add the desired buttons to the .dropdown-menu on click
  $dropdown_menu.html(btn_1 + btn_2 + btn_3);
  
  // show the dropdown menu so we can get its width height
  // currently hidden using css opacity: 0;
  $dropdown_menu.show();
  
  // dropdown menu width height
  var ddm_w = $dropdown_menu.outerWidth();
  var ddm_h = $dropdown_menu.outerHeight();

  // click position values inside button
  var click_x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  var click_y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
  
  // new translate positions for center menu
  var trans_x = click_x - (ddm_w / 2);
  var trans_y = click_y - (ddm_h / 2);

  // add this css to .dropdown-menu menu on click
  $dropdown_menu.css({
  
    // translate position to top left corner of dropdown
    'transform' : 'translate(' + trans_x + 'px,' + trans_y + 'px)',
    
    // reveal the dropdown menu
    'opacity' : 1
 
  });

});
```

```css
@import 'http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';

HTML,
BODY {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  cursor: crosshair;
  width: 100%;
}

BUTTON {
  cursor: crosshair !important;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- demo containers to center .btn-group please ignore this -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      
      <!-- question related code only -->
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-demo" type="button">
          Long demo button title for testing
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is the same as the example number 4 I provide, I would want to avoid using positions functions because of performance and it seems hacky something I can do just making the center's element first reference.

Comment: Interesting so do you want to use translate instead. I'm not sure if there is any other way unless we use translate? Is the container a fixed height?

Comment: No, it's not. I add children to it and removing depending of the button

Comment: Updated my answer not sure if this is what you're after?

Comment: But you are using top and left to move, and I want to use transform instead, I think I wil end up just doing that :/

Comment: I've added a translate only version at the end of my answer